# Read edges from .csv file to igraph using python

Tags: python, csv, igraph

Let's say I have a .csv file containing the following:

```
Apple    Banana
Apple    Coconut
Banana   Coconut
Coconut  Apple
```

And these should mean directed edges between two nodes, like:
Apple->Banana, Apple->Coconut, etc.

What is the proper method to use this kind of input in igraph?

Answer (score 8):

This is what the `Read_Ncol(f, names=True, weights="if_present", directed=True)` function exactly does.

http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#GraphBase.Read_Ncol

```
>>> from igraph import *
>>> g = Graph.Read_Ncol("stuff.csv", directed=True)
```

Comment: how is this accounting for different separators?